# Convert JSON Serialized String Containing HTML Entities into object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"[&quot;Software&quot;,&quot;3rd Party&quot;]"
```

How can I convert this to an object in javascript?

I familiar with converting HTML Entities to DOM Objects:

```
$("<div/>").html(encodedStr).text();
```

My situation is a little different than the one above. I don't want to create HTML, I need to create an object.

Comment: You have an HTML-escaped JSON string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the built-in [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var jstr = $("<div/>").html(encodedStr).text();
var obj = JSON.parse(jstr);
```

Since you're using jQuery anyway, you can use [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) instead of `JSON.parse()` if you need to support browsers [older than IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json). (jQuery simply calls `JSON.parse()` when it's available.)

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use ["he" library](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) with [JSON.parse](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp). "he" can encode and decode HTML code.

```
var str = he.decode("[&quot;Software&quot;,&quot;3rd Party&quot;]");
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```